# My nav submenu links are not changing color on hover?

Tags: css, css-selectors

It should be easy, but I can't figure it out!!!
here's the CSS:

```
nav {color: #505050; font-size: 15px; line-height: 18px; word-spacing: 13px; float: right; margin-right: 16px;padding-top: 36px; width: 60%;}


nav ul ul{display: none;}

nav ul li:hover > ul {display: block;/* [disabled]color: #ccc; */}

nav ul {padding: 0 5px;border-radius: 10px;list-style: none;position: relative; display: inline-table;}

nav ul:after {content: ""; clear: both; display: block; }

nav ul li {float: left;}

nav ul li:hover a {color: #e80031;}

nav ul li a {display: block; padding: 4px 12px;color: #505050; text-decoration: none;}

nav a {text-decoration: none;}

nav a:visited { color: #505050; }

nav a:hover {color: #e80031;text-decoration: none;text-weight: bold;}

nav ul ul {background: #FFF;border-radius: 5px;border: thin solid #CCC;padding: 0px;position: absolute;top: 100%;right: 70%;z-index: 50;word-spacing: .2em;}

nav ul ul li {float: none;color:#505050;/* [disabled]border-top: 1px solid #6b727c; *//* [disabled]border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; */position: relative;}

nav ul ul:hover a {color: #ccc;}

nav ul ul li:hover a {background: #ccc;}

nav ul ul li a:link {color:#e80031;}

nav ul ul li a:visited {/* [disabled]color:#e80031; */}

nav ul li.active a{color: #e80031;font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: Please also provide your HTML. CSS is nothing without HTML

Comment: please make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You should start using LESS or SASS :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the rules that might really affect your link colors are (*in order of specificity*)

```
nav a:hover {color: #e80031;text-decoration: none;text-weight: bold;}
nav ul li a {display: block; padding: 4px 12px;color: #505050; text-decoration: none;}

nav ul li:hover a {color: #e80031;}
nav ul ul:hover a {color: #ccc;}
nav ul li.active a{color: #e80031;font-weight: bold;}
```

the 3 in the end have the same specificity, so their order in your file will determine which applies if they match an element

For the submenu you can extend the `nav ul li:hover a {color: #e80031;}` rule to

```
nav ul li:hover a,
nav ul ul li:hover a {color: #e80031;}
```

---

Read http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity for more info, and play with a tool to compare them at http://specificity.keegan.st/

Comment: That is a slick comparison tool! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks guys. Very informative. Still can't figure out how to change the submenu text color on hover.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaby already mentioned, you've got some specificity wars happening here, but you also aren't clear which links you are experiencing not getting the proper color in your question. So, I'm making a wild guess here to say it might have to do with this rule:

```
nav ul ul:hover a {color: #ccc;}
```

Change that to this:

```
nav ul li:hover ul li a {color: #ccc;}
```

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/CzEcd

Comment: “Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.”

Comment: Cheers Keith (great name by the way). I'm Keith too.

Comment: The font/text on the submenu still isn't changing color.

Comment: You need to: 
a: add the HTML to your question, b: tell us what color the links in the submenu should be when hovered. Otherwise we are just shooting in the dark.

Comment: Another shot in the dark, I've updated the pen: http://codepen.io/keithwyland/pen/CzEcd is that what you need??